# sum of amount in all mysql table names from array

Tags: php, mysql

I have 6 mysql tables in my database.

and each table contains column `'amount'`

***I want sum of all amounts in all tables.***

But getting error as

```
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in //  foreach ($tablenames as $tablename) {
```

and

```
 undefined variable query
```

Code is as follows :

**I want specific tables from my database and more tables will be added per year which will contain `amount` column. So I extracted table names first.**

```
$tablenamearray = array(); 
    
$tablenamequery = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'databasename' and table_name LIKE '%registration%'";

$tablenameres = $database->get_results($tablenamequery);
foreach ($tablenameres as $tablenamedata){
    $tablenamearray[]=$tablenamedata['table_name'];
}

$tablenamearray_final =   "'".join("', '",$tablenamearray)."'"; 
$tablenamesrcvd = "array(".$tablenamearray_final.");";

///$tablenamesrcvd are as given below when I echo
// array('table_1','table_2','table_3','table_4','table_5','table_6'); 

foreach ($tablenamesrcvd as $tablename) {
    $query = "select SUM(`amount`) as Total from $tablename";
    $res = $database->get_results($query); // using wrapper class
    foreach ($res as $data){
        $totalrcvd = $data['Total'];
    }       
}
```

What I am missing ?

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with the foreach declaration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ddd5183e52be5110f4e1cc935b9f54a982760d9). Are you sure the error pertains to that line? Perhaps it's a different foreach.

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from `foreach ($tablenames as $tablename) {`?

Comment: Yes... In my testing page, it is on line 117 and it is for that foreach...

Comment: The problem is not clear from just the snippet you've posted. Please post more/all of the code.

Comment: @David Yes.. I am editing question with some more code..

Comment: Something must be reassigning `$tablenames` before the `foreach`

Comment: Side note: `$totalrcvd = $data['Total'];` should be `$totalrcvd += $data['Total'];`

Comment: Is the loop inside a function? Do you pass `$tablenames` as a function parameter?

Comment: What is `$tablenamesrcvd` for?

Comment: @Barmar $tablenamesrcvd  for creating array

Comment: But you're not using it for anything, you just use the hard-coded `$tablenames` array.

Comment: @Barmar $tablenames is taken as example for this question

Comment: Show the ACTUAL code, because that's where the problem is.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a string containing `array(...)`. It won't be treated as an array. You should be using `$tablenamearray`

Comment: @Barmar but it is giving output as array('table_1','table_2','table_3','table_4','table_5','table_6');

Comment: You would need to use `eval($tablenamesrcvd)` to convert that to an actual array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$tablenamesrcvd` is a string, not an array.

The variable `$tablenamearray` contains the array of table names, you can loop over that. You don't need to convert it to a string.

You should also add to `$totalrcvd`, not reassign it each time through the loop, using `+=` instead of `=`.

```
$totalrcvd = 0;
foreach ($tablenamesarray as $tablename) {
    $query = "select SUM(`amount`) as Total from $tablename";
    $res = $database->get_results($query); // using wrapper class
    foreach ($res as $data){
        $totalrcvd += $data['Total'];
    }       
}
echo $totalrcvd;
```

Comment: Yes... It worked... Thanks for clearing my ideas... thnx

Comment: I tested and checked again... But this code is giving sum of last table only... e.g. table_6 in my above question...

Comment: when I manually added each table name in sum query, it is working...

Comment: Did you change `$totalrcvd =` to `$totalrcvd +=` so it adds up all the results?

Comment: Yes... till issue is same

Comment: Make sure the initialization to `0` is outside the loop.

Comment: Does `$tablenamesarray` have all the table names?